# How to move and resize partitions Ubuntu+windows dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have a laptop with a dual boot Windows/Ubuntu.
I'd like to move and resize the partitions, as the default installation put Ubuntu on a 12GB partition and I'd like to use more.
I have booted my system from a USB stick, started G-parted, but the situation looks a bit complex: my Ubuntu partition is blocked by the Linux swap partition and I don't know how to move it.

[image]

Partition /dev/sda5 is not needed, (it's Windows D disk).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

1. Backup your important data! Messing with partitions is dangerous!
2. Delete the `sda7` swap partition and `sda5` data partition, and extend your main `sda6` to fill all the unallocated space except 8GB at the end (which you will use for your new swap partition)
3. Create a new swap partition in the remaining 8GB of unallocated space
4. Follow [this Q&A on Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/170499/changing-linux-swap-partition) to change your installation to use your new swap partition

Comment: Thanks, it worked, I had to re-install GRUB after it as it was corrupted, but after fixing this I had my partitions resized (and no loss of data).